# git diff for large SQL files

Tags: git

I have a large SQL file (1.3 G). When committing updated versions git stores the entire file repeatedly. I have tracked down the problem to diff.

I think there is some size limit on diff, because I get

```
git diff --cached
fatal: unable to generate diff for sql/dump.sql
```

I tried increasing the big file threshold, but it does not seem to be doing anything. Git does not treat the SQL file as binary. How can I make diff work for large files?

Comment: You seem to assume git should be storing just the diff.  That's not how git works.  When it packs objects, it may (as part of compressing the pack) deltify the older version, but loose objects are always stored independent of any other version.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger but why can I not run diff on the large files? And why is it not compressing them at all? If I change a line in the SQL file, the database doubles in size.

Comment: I don't know why you'd get that result from diff; which is why I didn't post as an answer or try to address that point (yet).  It doesn't compress them at all because, as I just said, that's how git works. It only compresses objects in pack files, not when initially creating them as loose objects.

Comment: Unfortunately the error reporting in the `diff` code path is not terribly informative. I dug around for the error in question, but can only say that it means git gave up on the diff for some reason - my guess would be it failed to allocate a buffer, but that's just a guess. I'm not sure it's really connected to your root question, though. Even when pack files are created, the deltification is done on a totally different code path than the one used for a user-readable diff

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger yes, the big file threshold actually fixed my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is. In `xdiff-integerface.h` there is a `MAX_XDIFF_SIZE` along with some explanation.  If you can guarantee that the actual diff will be less in size you can up the value a bit.